# Using xDebug with Yii with custom folder structure

Tags: yii, xdebug, phpstorm

The problem is that breaks don't work with files, that were moved out of webroot.

When all files were under the webroot all was OK:

```
z:\home\mysite.dev\www\framework\
z:\home\mysite.dev\www\protected\
z:\home\mysite.dev\www\index.php
```

Because of the specifics of the project, I have moved /framework and /protected out of webroot:

```
z:\common\yii\framework\
z:\home\mysite.dev\protected\
z:\home\mysite.dev\www\index.php
```

And so now the breaks on index.php in some /framework files are working, other don't. It seems to be I should make some tricky server mapping for xdebug, can anybody give me a hint?

xdebug settings from php.ini:

```
zend_extension="\usr\local\php5\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9.dll"
xdebug.auto_trace = 0
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
xdebug.manual_url = "http://www.php.net"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

Win7x64
Denwer3
PHPStorm 6.0.3

Comment: What is the **project** root? Does IDE knows about files/folders that are outside of the project root (if any)?

Comment: The project root is
    z:\home\mysite.dev\
And yes, framework is connected as external library in PhpStorm

Comment: Did you mapped framework folders properly (`Settings | PHP | Servers`)? Generally speaking it's all about mapping (in most cases, considering that xdebug itself is configured and working properly) as it does not matter what framework you are using (xdebug does not care as long as it (and IDE) can access those files)